# Tiny MCE Problem

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a problem with the Tiny MCE Editor. In IE When i Copy - paste some HTML content from any where into the Tiny Mce Editor and when i select the portion of the pasted content, i Get a Boxed Border..!! Thats really annoying & while i scroll the editor - it gets out of the editor area. i want to remove/avoid this border.

[image]

Comment: That is a weird bug, does it happen on the official TinyMCE demo?

Comment: ya it does, try it, try pasting a image from a page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you pasting from Microsoft Excel? I tried pasting from web, Word, Excel, and PowerPoint into TinyMCE running in Firefox 3.6 and Internet Explorer 7, and in both browsers I get this when pasting from Excel. it might be worth looking into configuring the paste plugin, where you may be able to detect when this box appears and then remove it. http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

Comment: Thank u for your clue. but i just realized that these border things r 'drag handles' to resize the image(actually) and these r appearing for text some times!. FF is good, at-least the handles do not overflow out of the editor. IE is pathetic in this case.
i think simple solution will be to disable image resizing..!! is that a good option.!!? if so, Does anyone know how to DISABLE the image resize feature in Tinymce?

Comment: Perhaps you could disable the 'img' tag if you don't need images at all. You could do this by setting invalid_elements in the init method, as seen [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:invalid_elements)